# How to rotate entire macOS application

Tags: swift, macos

**TLDR;** I want to rotate an entire macOS app, that I wrote in Swift and for which I can modify the code, by 90 degrees. See the image for an example (I choose one random app just for the sake of showing what I mean); every UI element except for the window bar should be rotated.

[image]

**Background.**
I have written a macOS app, in Swift, for personal use and sometimes I use it on the iPad by connecting the iPad to the Mac with Sidecar. The interface is more useful when the width of the screen is smaller than the height (i.e. portrait mode), but, unlike my monitor that can be physically rotated, I have found no way of using Sidecar with a portrait mode resolution. So, since I can edit the code of my app, the easiest solution is to rotate every UI element. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Do a transform on the containing view?

Comment: You can setup a layout based on screen aspect ratio. For example you know it's landscape if  `width > height` or portrait if `width < height`

Comment: @matt I tried using this code `self.view.wantsLayer = true` and `self.view.layer!.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat.pi, 0, 0, 1)` in my main `ViewController` but it has no effect. If I apply this code explicitly to the main subview that I add to the view of the main `ViewController` I end up with a flickering window.

Comment: Yeah, it was kind of a crazy idea. But _your_ idea is kind of a crazy idea. :) Of course the _real_ problem here is that Sidecar has no portrait mode, which is just idiotic and I'm sure Apple has heard about that from all sides.